# Java File Permission Problems

Tags: java, recursion, file-permissions

I'm trying to write a method using Java which will recursively search for .exe files.  The problem I'm having is when it comes to the directory of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\CrashReports"

It seems like no matter what I attempt I always get a NullPointerException due to this file. I've tried making sure that I either don't add it to the list of files to be recursively checked, or at least to skip over it if it does make it into the list of files to be examined.

As it stands my code is incorrect, however this may very well be a logical fallacy rather, I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to how Java thinks it can read this file.

```
private static List<String> exefiles = new ArrayList<String>();
public void findExe(File rootDir) throws SecurityException, IOException{
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(rootDir.listFiles()));
    List<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>();
    Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator();
    if(files.size() > 0){
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            File currentFile = iterator.next();
            if(currentFile.getName().endsWith(".exe")){
                exefiles.add(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }else if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
                if(currentFile.canRead()){
                    System.out.println("We can read " + currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if(currentFile.listFiles().length > 0){
                        System.out.println(currentFile.getAbsolutePath() + " has a length greater than 0");
                        directories.add(currentFile);
                    }else{System.out.println(currentFile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not have any files in it");}
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Could not add " + currentFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to directories because it could not be read");
                }
            }else;
        }
    }
```

When I open the files properties with Windows, the System and Administrator groups have full control, while the Users group only has "special permissions."

I know that Java 7 provides easier ways to deal with attributes via the java.nio.file package, but this option is unsuitable for my needs.

Comment: Why are you including that `else;`? What's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, not just a general description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listFiles will return null if you do not pass it a directory, or if you pass it something it can't handle properly, like a junction point. Using other packages may be able to verify if you are looking at a junction point, but you can't do this with the basic files API. So that being said, you can instead just do a quick check for nullity, so change

```
}else if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
```

to

```
}else if(currentFile.isDirectory() && currentFile.listFiles()!=null){
```